# Deadlock in producer consumer program

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have written a code for producer consumer problem using events. And the problem is consumer thread is taking over the producer thread and its in a state of deadlock . However the code is working fine with mutex .Please let me know where exactly is the problem .

I have made an assumption that the maximum buffer size is 50.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<Windows.h>
  #include<WinBase.h>

  int Buffersize=0;


  HANDLE datanew;

  void producer()
  {

 while(1)
 {
     if(Buffersize==50)
     {
       Sleep(1000);

      }
      printf("\n Inside the producer routine ");
      Buffersize++;
      printf("\n Number of Items in the buffer = %d",Buffersize);
      SetEvent(datanew);

  }
  }

 void consumer()
 {


while(1)
{
     if(Buffersize==0)
     {
       Sleep(1000);

     }
     printf("\n Inside the consumer routine ");


     if (WaitForSingleObject(datanew,INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0){

     Buffersize--;
     ResetEvent(datanew);

     printf("\n Number of Items in the buffer = %d",Buffersize);

  }
 }

   int main()
   {
   DWORD idprod,idcons;
   HANDLE datanew=CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,TRUE,NULL);
   HANDLE threadarray[2];

  HANDLE prodhnd=CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)producer,0,0,&idprod);
  HANDLE conshnd=CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)consumer,0,0,&idcons);
  threadarray[0]=prodhnd;
  threadarray[1]=conshnd;


  WaitForMultipleObjects(2,threadarray, TRUE, INFINITE);

   for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
       {
         CloseHandle(threadarray[i]);

       }

 }
```

Comment: Oh dear.  Get rid of the sleep loop in the consumer. Replace the unfit-for-purpose manual reset event with a semaphore.  Replace 'Buffersize++' etc. with atomic operations, (or protect with a mutex).

Comment: `Buffersize` is accessed from both threads concurrently, this is not going to work out well. You need to add critical section to prevent from this.

Comment: @MartinJames ; yes it works fine with mutex locks , was trying to work the same with event.

Comment: @SanthoshPai - just because it appears to work doesn't mean that it is safe.  Concurrent programming is hard and not it is never safe to access a variable in different threads without a lock or using atomic operations.

Comment: Yup i'm learning winapi programming and its my first time with this thread synchronization object called as event . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global mutex handle `datanew` is never assigned.  In `main()` you are assigning a mutex to a local variable named `datanew`, not the global `datanew`.  So `producer()` and `consumer()` have no synchronization.

Remove the `HANDLE` from the line `HANDLE datanew=CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,TRUE,NULL);` in main().

Comment: Oh god , such an silly mistake. Works like charm now.Thanks a lot mate .